# How to map dynamic property to element bracket function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to map a state property as value to a generated form input with react, but have been unsuccessful so far. The example below shows what im trying to do, but the wrong way as group.value is imported as a string, and wont be compiled into the value of the state variable. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I need both the final object and property to be dynamically called  (in this example frame and brand/year/model)

Map function:

```
return frameData.map((group) => {
            return (
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            id={group.name}
                            name={group.name}
                            placeholder={group.placeHolder}
                            value={group.value}
                            onChange={(event) => this.updateValue(event)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
```

dataset

```
const frameData = [
    {
        name: "frame-brand",
        placeHolder: "Brand",
        value: "{this.state.newSubmission.frame.brand}",
    },
    {
        name: "frame-year",
        placeHolder: "Year",
        value: "{this.state.newSubmission.frame.year}",
    },
    {
        name: "frame-model",
        placeHolder: "Model",
        value: "{this.state.newSubmission.frame.model}",
    },
];
```

state

```
    this.state = {
        newSubmission: 
          frame: {
            year: "",
            model: "",
            brand: "",
          }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to achieve is cool, but instead of passing the variable name i,e the entire state object, you can just pass the `key` and you can assign that to the `<input />` component.

```
const frameData = [
    {
        name: "frame-brand",
        placeHolder: "Brand",
        value: "brand",
    },
    {
        name: "frame-year",
        placeHolder: "Year",
        value: "year",
    },
    {
        name: "frame-model",
        placeHolder: "Model",
        value: "model",
    },
];
```

and in the map function, you can use

```
return frameData.map((group) => {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id={group.name}
                        name={group.name}
                        placeholder={group.placeHolder}
                        value={this.state.newSubmission.frame[group.value]}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateValue(event)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
```

Comment: This is actually how i tried it first, it doesnt work either unfortunately.

Comment: oh ok polar, but i guess this is the correct way of accessing the state object dynamically, if i am not wrong, can you please try the same with logging the values to the console, before returning the element

Comment: one property seems to work ok, but the issue is i need two levels of dynamic properties to access so my call is something like this.state.newSubmission.[group.value][group.value2] which produces the error TypeError: this.state.newSubmission[group.value] is undefined

Comment: So i guess the question is really how to call a property and sub property dynamically one after another, sorry for not being more clear i have updated my post to clarify

Comment: this.state[first.key][firstChild.key][firstchildChild.key], you can access the objects based on its hierrarchy, and no need of "." before [ ] in your case => " this.state.newSubmission.[group.value][group.value2]"

Comment: this.state.newSubmission[group.value][group.value2] produces the error TypeError: this.state.newSubmission[group.value] is undefined